# Showing $f(z)=x^2+iy^3$ is not analytic anywhere

Tags: complex-analysis

I want to show that the following function is not analytic anywhere. $$f(z)=x^2+iy^3$$

Now I don't really understand the Cauchy-Riemann equations, but it seems we take:

$$u(x,y)=x^2,v(x,y)=y^3$$
as we normally would, and take the partial derivatives:

$$u_x =2x, u_v = 0$$
$$v_x = 0, v_y = 3y^2$$

And we want:

$$u_x=v_y,u_y = -v_x$$

For necessary condition for being analytic at some point.

$$2x=3y^2,0=0$$

So we are potentially(not necessarily) analytic and any point such that $2x=3y^2$ I believe.

---

Now, how then I have ruled out almost every point, how do I rule out these remaining points?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note the precise statement of the theorem. http://www.math.columbia.edu/~rf/complex2.pdf Go to the theorem on page 8. The CR equations must hold on an OPEN subset. A single point or line is not that.

Comment: Since for any open ball around a point on that line, you will find points that don't satisfy the CR equations, the function is not analytic. @SkiesBurn

Comment: Why is$f(z)=x^2-y^2 + 2xyi$ analytic?

It has $u_x=2x=v_y$ and $u_y=-2y=-v_x$ and $f'(z)=2z$

How do I deduce it is an open subset?

Comment: $u_x=v_y$ and $u_y=-v_x$ for all $x,y$. Certainly all of $\mathbb{C}$ is open.@SkiesBurn

Comment: Wait I think I misunderstood something.

Do the Cauchy Riemann equations require that $u_x=v_y$ and $u_y=-v_x$ **in general** or do I set these, and find which points it isn't true?

Comment: @SkiesBurn read the link I sent you. If the CR equations hold on an open subset of C, then the function is analytic on that subset.

Comment: Oh I see now thank you. We have satisfaction at $(0,0)$ which makes it not open and hence it is nowhere analytic.

Comment: But the function is complex differential at $\{z = x+iy \mid 2x = 3y^2 \}$, right?